# Cannot create new subsite in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, permissions

When I tried to create a new subsite under a site collection, I get the error message "Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you." after I click the "Create" button. I entered the newsbweb.aspx by clicking Site contents -> new subsite.

This site collection is create by other people. But I am now the primary administrator of this site collection. I checked the "share list" of this site collection, I am on it. I tried grant myself all kinds of privilege but none of them helps. The creator of this site collection who is now the secondary administrator still can successfully create subsites. And I can access and modify the subsites he created. I am also able to create another site collection and create subsite under the site collection I created.

Anyone knows what I can do to successfully create a subsite in this particular site collection? Thank you very much.

Gavin